# Set Angular material input type=number increment to more than one

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to know if is possible to change the increment range of the material input with type number, default is 1, but what if I want to change it to  10,000. Is doable?

[image: Input type number increments]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you add `step="10000"` to your `input` tag you should be able to accomplish this. Note, it is just html markup and not a property of the material library.

I can't see your code but it should look something like this:

```
<input type="number" step="10000" matInput [formControl]="yourFormControl">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use step property of HTML Input tag:

```
<input type="number" name="points" step="10000">
```